# What is the best way to label objects in an ASP.NET page. (resources in the database)

Tags: asp.net, label, controls, multilingual

I wonder what would be the best way to label objects (label, gridview columns, ValidatorCallout) in a asp.net page, with that information (text) are on a table in the database (the table has the id of object name Language1, language 2).

What I have today is a method that gets all the controls on the page I am opening language of the user and are logged in, and it does a query on the table by passing the "id screen" that returns all objects of the same. After this is done in a loop all controls from the screen where you check the type of control (Label, RequiredFieldValidator) to properly to set the property (.Text if Label, .ErrorMessage if RequiredFieldValidator) unfortunately it is VERY SLOW. Is there a best practice to do this?

Note: App_LocalResources (.resx) does not serve to my case.

Method:

```
 public void RotularObjetos(Control ctl)
        {
            foreach (Control c in ctl.Controls)
            {
                if (c.GetType() == typeof(Label))
                {
                    var dicionario = ambiente.ListaObjeto(this.Modulo, this.IdEmpresa, this.IdIdioma, this.IdUsuario,
                                                          ((Label)(c)).ID);

                    if (dicionario == null)
                    {
                        ambiente.IncluirDicionarioObjeto(this.Modulo, this.IdIdioma, 0, ((Label)(c)).ID,
                                                         AutoWare.FrameWork.ManterAmbiente.TipoObjeto.Label.GetHashCode(),
                                                         ((Label)(c)).Text,
                                                         ((Label)(c)).ToolTip == string.Empty
                                                             ? ((Label)(c)).Text
                                                             : ((Label)(c)).ToolTip);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ((Label)(c)).Text = dicionario.DS_ALIAS;
                        ((Label)(c)).ToolTip = dicionario.DS_HELP;
                    }
                }
                else if (c.GetType() == typeof(RequiredFieldValidator))
                {
                    var dicionario = ambiente.ListaObjeto(this.Modulo, this.IdEmpresa, this.IdIdioma, this.IdUsuario,
                                                          ((RequiredFieldValidator)(c)).ID);

                    if (dicionario == null)
                    {
                        ambiente.IncluirDicionarioObjeto(this.Modulo, this.IdIdioma, 0,
                                                         ((RequiredFieldValidator)(c)).ID,
                                                         AutoWare.FrameWork.ManterAmbiente.TipoObjeto
                                                                 .RequiredFieldValidator.GetHashCode(),
                                                         ((RequiredFieldValidator)(c)).ErrorMessage,
                                                         ((RequiredFieldValidator)(c)).ToolTip == string.Empty
                                                             ? ((RequiredFieldValidator)(c)).ErrorMessage
                                                             : ((RequiredFieldValidator)(c)).ToolTip);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ((RequiredFieldValidator)(c)).ErrorMessage = dicionario.DS_ALIAS;
                        ((RequiredFieldValidator)(c)).ToolTip = dicionario.DS_HELP;
                    }
                }
                else if (c.GetType() == typeof(LinkButton))
                {
                    var dicionario = ambiente.ListaObjeto(this.Modulo, this.IdEmpresa, this.IdIdioma, this.IdUsuario,
                                                          ((LinkButton)(c)).ID);

                    if (dicionario == null)
                    {
                        ambiente.IncluirDicionarioObjeto(this.Modulo, this.IdIdioma, 0, ((LinkButton)(c)).ID,
                                                         AutoWare.FrameWork.ManterAmbiente.TipoObjeto.LinkButton
                                                                 .GetHashCode(), ((LinkButton)(c)).Text,
                                                         ((LinkButton)(c)).ToolTip == string.Empty
                                                             ? ((LinkButton)(c)).Text
                                                             : ((LinkButton)(c)).ToolTip);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ((LinkButton)(c)).Text = dicionario.DS_ALIAS;
                        ((LinkButton)(c)).ToolTip = dicionario.DS_HELP;
                    }
                }
                else if (c.GetType() == typeof(ImageButton))
                {
                    var dicionario = ambiente.ListaObjeto(this.Modulo, this.IdEmpresa, this.IdIdioma, this.IdUsuario,
                                                          ((ImageButton)(c)).ID);

                    if (dicionario == null)
                    {
                        ambiente.IncluirDicionarioObjeto(this.Modulo, this.IdIdioma, 0, ((ImageButton)(c)).ID,
                                                         AutoWare.FrameWork.ManterAmbiente.TipoObjeto.ImageButton
                                                                 .GetHashCode(), string.Empty,
                                                         ((ImageButton)(c)).ToolTip == string.Empty
                                                             ? string.Empty
                                                             : ((ImageButton)(c)).ToolTip);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ((ImageButton)(c)).ToolTip = dicionario.DS_HELP;
                    }
                }
                else if (c.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox))
                {
                    var dicionario = ambiente.ListaObjeto(this.Modulo, this.IdEmpresa, this.IdIdioma, this.IdUsuario,
                                                          ((CheckBox)(c)).ID);

                    if (dicionario == null)
                    {
                        ambiente.IncluirDicionarioObjeto(this.Modulo, this.IdIdioma, 0, ((CheckBox)(c)).ID,
                                                         AutoWare.FrameWork.ManterAmbiente.TipoObjeto.CheckBox
                                                                 .GetHashCode(), string.Empty,
                                                         ((CheckBox)(c)).ToolTip == string.Empty
                                                             ? string.Empty
                                                             : ((CheckBox)(c)).ToolTip);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ((CheckBox)(c)).Text = dicionario.DS_ALIAS;
                        ((CheckBox)(c)).ToolTip = dicionario.DS_HELP;
                    }
                }
                else if (c.GetType() == typeof(Button))
                {
                    var dicionario = ambiente.ListaObjeto(this.Modulo, this.IdEmpresa, this.IdIdioma, this.IdUsuario,
                                                          ((Button)(c)).ID);

                    if (dicionario == null)
                    {
                        ambiente.IncluirDicionarioObjeto(this.Modulo, this.IdIdioma, 0, ((Button)(c)).ID,
                                                         AutoWare.FrameWork.ManterAmbiente.TipoObjeto.Button.GetHashCode
                                                             (), ((Button)(c)).Text,
                                                         ((Button)(c)).ToolTip == string.Empty
                                                             ? ((Button)(c)).Text
                                                             : ((Button)(c)).ToolTip);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ((Button)(c)).Text = dicionario.DS_ALIAS;
                        ((Button)(c)).ToolTip = dicionario.DS_HELP;
                    }
                }
                else if (c.GetType() == typeof(RadioButton))
                {
                    var dicionario = ambiente.ListaObjeto(this.Modulo, this.IdEmpresa, this.IdIdioma, this.IdUsuario,
                                                          ((RadioButton)(c)).ID);

                    if (dicionario == null)
                    {
                        ambiente.IncluirDicionarioObjeto(this.Modulo, this.IdIdioma, 0, ((RadioButton)(c)).ID,
                                                         AutoWare.FrameWork.ManterAmbiente.TipoObjeto.RadioButton
                                                                 .GetHashCode(), ((RadioButton)(c)).Text,
                                                         ((RadioButton)(c)).ToolTip == string.Empty
                                                             ? ((RadioButton)(c)).Text
                                                             : ((RadioButton)(c)).ToolTip);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ((RadioButton)(c)).Text = dicionario.DS_ALIAS;
                        ((RadioButton)(c)).ToolTip = dicionario.DS_HELP;
                    }
                }
                else if (c.GetType() == typeof(GridView))
                {
                    var grid = ambiente.ListaObjeto(this.Modulo, this.IdEmpresa, this.IdIdioma, this.IdUsuario,
                                                    ((GridView)(c)).ID);

                    if (grid == null)
                    {
                        ambiente.IncluirDicionarioObjeto(this.Modulo, this.IdIdioma, 0, ((GridView)(c)).ID,
                                                         AutoWare.FrameWork.ManterAmbiente.TipoObjeto.GridView
                                                                 .GetHashCode(), ((GridView)(c)).ToolTip,
                                                         ((GridView)(c)).ToolTip);
                        grid = ambiente.ListaObjeto(this.Modulo, this.IdEmpresa, this.IdIdioma, this.IdUsuario,
                                                    ((GridView)(c)).ID);

                        foreach (DataControlField child in ((GridView)(c)).Columns)
                        {
                            var coluna = ambiente.ListaObjeto(this.Modulo, grid.ID_DICIONARIO_OBJETO, this.IdEmpresa,
                                                              this.IdIdioma, this.IdUsuario, child.HeaderText);
                            if (coluna == null && child.HeaderText != string.Empty)
                                ambiente.IncluirDicionarioObjeto(this.Modulo, this.IdIdioma, grid.ID_DICIONARIO_OBJETO,
                                                                 child.HeaderText,
                                                                 AutoWare.FrameWork.ManterAmbiente.TipoObjeto
                                                                         .GridViewColumn.GetHashCode(), child.HeaderText,
                                                                 child.HeaderText);
                            else if (coluna != null)
                                child.HeaderText = coluna.DS_ALIAS;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ((GridView)(c)).ToolTip = grid.DS_HELP;

                        foreach (DataControlField child in ((GridView)(c)).Columns)
                        {
                            var coluna = ambiente.ListaObjeto(this.Modulo, grid.ID_DICIONARIO_OBJETO, this.IdEmpresa,
                                                              this.IdIdioma, this.IdUsuario, child.HeaderText);
                            if (coluna == null && child.HeaderText != string.Empty)
                                ambiente.IncluirDicionarioObjeto(this.Modulo, this.IdIdioma, grid.ID_DICIONARIO_OBJETO,
                                                                 child.HeaderText,
                                                                 AutoWare.FrameWork.ManterAmbiente.TipoObjeto
                                                                         .GridViewColumn.GetHashCode(), child.HeaderText,
                                                                 child.HeaderText);
                            else if (coluna != null)
                                child.HeaderText = coluna.DS_ALIAS;
                        }
                    }
                }

                RotularObjetos(c);
            }
        }
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you post the code that performs the property setting?

Comment: I added the function I use, within the question. hugs